# How to assign InfoWindow to OverlayItem in OSMDroid?

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am showing a huge amount of places to my osmdroid map as `OverlayItem`,
in `Marker` it is possible to `setInfoWindow`, but how to do that in `OverlayItem` ?
I prefer using `OverlayItem` because it supports `setEnabled` feature to hide it in specific zoom levels.

Update: Due to have a lot of places to show, `Marker` was not a good choice, because in low zoom levels all the view of the map was covered by Markers. So I switched to show places using `OverlayItem` but now I can't show `InfoWindows` or bubbles `onTap` of each place to show more info.

Comment: 1) setEnabled is also available to Markers. 2) I don't understand why/how OverlayItems could be better than Markers to not cover the map. 3) Using Markers, you can use the RadiusMarkerClusterer - not available with OverlayItems.

Comment: Hi, tnx for answering, How to show Markers only in Current map view not all markers? @MKer

Comment: I am handling thousands of Markers so I am looking for a solution to be a little more Memory-friendly and can be hidden on small zoom levels when a city or a state is shown in current display

Comment: You can share the icon and the infoWindow between multiple Markers. You can also set android:largeHeap="true" to get more memory. Are you sure the memory print is significatively different between Markers and OverlayItems?